# MPMoviePlayerController Add custom Play button

Tags: iphone, ios

Currently i am working on a iPhone Application Which is displaying video. I have used MPMoviePlayController to load the Video from the local folder.

Can we customize the Standard media player ? What i want to do is to hide all the standard elements (Play, Forward, Rewind, Done) and just to build the player with a single play button with a customized image . Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can surely add custom controls for MPMoviePlayerController. For that first hide existing controls using, [***MPMovieControlStyle***](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), set this to ***MPMovieControlStyleNone***

Now add your custom control buttons and handle all the MoviePlayer events over there, like;

- Play
- Pause
- Stop
- Prev
- Next, etc.
- Or you can add your own controls like jump to this time (+10 sec, +20 sec), movie speed control (1x, 2x, ..), etc.

Hope this will be useful for you.

Comment: moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

Comment: but its possible to add all these custom controls on full screen mode? Please suggest. thx

Comment: Yes first load your video in full screen mode. Over that view add/load   another view which contains only your control (transparent view). There you go...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have any controlStyle of apple and still want to add some custom buttons on movie view. You can subclass MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Let say you have MyCustomMoviePlayerViewController as subclass of MPMoviePlayerViewController then in  MyCustomMoviePlayerViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"MyCustomButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview :button];
    }
```