# MPMoviePlayerController Contols Glows On Tap IOS

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

HI I am new in IOS Development . I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play video's . Video Plays well 
But I when click on play button play button glows , I want to disable this. I'm using MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded control style.

Following link to show my problem

https://app.box.com/s/1o1bwbsk7x0qel476jm1

Answer (score 0):

Each UIButton contains one property `Shows Touch on Highlight`. For MPMoviePlayerController buttons, this property is by default set to YES, internally in iOS SDK itself.

But if you required it then you have to disable this default controls, and add your own custom control over MoviePlayer.

Refer: [MPMoviePlayerController Add custom Play button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248773/mpmovieplayercontroller-add-custom-play-button)

**Suggestion:**

I would suggest not to change Apple default behavior.

They have added this functionality for presentation purpose. When presenting your app on big screen, how audience will come to know that where presenter has tapped. For that they have display glow effect, when user touches, so that audience will get aware what/why actually that event has happened.

Comment: Thanks for reply me ,  I know it's look good , but my boss want to remove this effect.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible with default controls. Either can convey the reason, why Apple has given that or write your own custom controls and play with that.